# Объясните поведение моего цикла python

Tags: python, python-3.x

В общем, есть файл csv типа, в котором 2 столбца, разделенных точкой с запятой. 
Часть нужной мне инфы в левом столбце, часть в правом
Если запись содержит 'some100' в левой части - нужная мне инфа в правой.

Данным кодом я решаю свою задачу, но он не работает в один этап. Чтобы решить свою задачу мне нужно
сначала записать non-target, комментируя остальное, затем target.
Если запускаю всё вместе - target возвращает пустой список.

С чем это связано?

```
def check_and_replace():


    f = open('PATH\\link_list.txt', 'r')
    non_target = [i for i in f if 'some100' not in i.split(';')[0]]


    target = [i for i in f if 'some100' in i.split(';')[0]]


    f = open('PATH\\new_link_list.txt', 'a')

    for i in target:

        f.write(i.replace('http://site.ru/?action=some100;', ''))


    for i in non_target:
        f.write(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема связанна скорее всего с тем что чтение из файла идёт с помощью буферизации, и после первого прохода в цикле данные из буфера удаляются.

`non_target = [i for i in f if 'some100' not in i.split(';')[0]]`

после этого цикла буфер пустой.

Попробуйте обработать содержимое файла в одном цикле.
Заменив вот это

```
non_target = [i for i in f if 'some100' not in i.split(';')[0]]
target = [i for i in f if 'some100' in i.split(';')[0]]
```

на

```
non_target = []
target = []
for i in f:
    if 'some100' not in i.split(';')[0]:
        non_target.append(i)
    else:
        target.append(i)
f.close()
```